# WPF ComboBox interaction of IsEditable, ItemsSource, and ValidationRule

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

What I'm trying to do is the following. I've got a combo box bound to a custom class with ItemsSource, DisplayMembePath set to a property of that class. This itself works great, all the binding works. Skip to the bottom for my problems.

```
        <ComboBox Name="Field" Width="{Binding FieldWidth}" ItemsSource="{Binding LookupValues}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}" 
              Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding FieldAlignment}" Margin="{Binding FieldMargin}" IsEditable="True"/>
```

My custom class is pretty basic:

```
public class LookupValue : ILookupValue
{
    public LookupValue() { }
    public LookupValue(CODETABLE codeTable)
    {
        Id = codeTable.ID;
        Name = codeTable.CODE;
        Description = codeTable.DESCR;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? Sequence { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is LookupValue)
        {
            LookupValue lookupValue = (LookupValue)obj;
            return Id == lookupValue.Id && String.Compare(Name, lookupValue.Name) == 0 && String.Compare(Description, lookupValue.Description) == 0;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id;
    }
```

As is the relevant section of my view model

```
    public ILookupValue SelectedValue
    {
        get {
            return (ILookupValue)GetValue(SelectedValueProperty);
        }
        set { SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedValue"); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValue", typeof(ILookupValue), typeof(MarriageComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(new MarriageLookupValue(), SelectedValueChanged));

    private static void SelectedValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MarriageComboBox box = d as MarriageComboBox;
    }

    public IList<ILookupValue> LookupValues
    {
        get { return (IList<ILookupValue>)GetValue(LookupValuesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LookupValuesProperty, value); NotifyPropertyChanged("LookupValues"); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LookupValuesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LookupValues", typeof(IList<ILookupValue>), typeof(MarriageComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Everything works except for the IsEditable=true part on the ComboBox. The requirement is that the user is allowed to enter in their own values and not have to be one of the things in the list. But for required fields, I also need to validate that something was entered or selected.

**My issues:**

- I am using ValidationRules for the check, but for custom entries it always gets sent a null value.
- The binding only updates whenever the selection is changed to a new pre-defined option. It does not update when I type in a custom value, or when what I'm typing deviates from a pre-defined option. For example, if USA is an option and I type Underpants, it will update to USA when I type the U, but then stay on USA as I type the rest of the word. And if I start with a letter not matching anything in the list, it will remain empty.

**What I've Tried:**

- At the advice of some other similar, but not the same, questions, I've tried adding a null check and creation of a new LookupValue to my SelectedValue getter. This seems to have no effect.
- I've also tried binding to a list of strings and handling the matching to my list of custom class myself, but even for the list of strings the behavior is the same.
- I've managed to work around the second issue by tying into the KeyUp event and setting the SelectedValue to a new LookupValue if there is no match. But that still doesn't help with the ValidationRules issue.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I think it would be best to fully describe the behavior that you are looking to achieve here. Most `ComboBox` controls I have used/seen work this way: User clicks `ComboBox`. User can select an item from drop down with mouse, arrows, or by typing. Typing a matching word with rapid key strokes will highlight that item in the `ComboBox`. From the sounds of what you are asking, you might need to modify the template and create a custom `ComboBox`.

Comment: I'm looking for exactly as you describe, with the added functionality of being able to submit custom information not in the list.

Comment: You really need to create a custom `ComboBox` control then. If you need help with that, let me know. I recommend NOT making an editable field but instead use a `TextBox` to insert new data. Two reasons for this: It is easier and it is more intuitive to the user. Again, let me know if you need help.

Comment: Definitely my preferred solution would be to add an "Other" option and then have a new text box pop up if they select it, like any other decent form. But I am unfortunately constrained by the mad designs of someone else who doesn't want that.

Comment: You will need a custom `ComboBox` control then or create a control from the ground up to do what you want. `ComboBox` controls have properties such as `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem` and I am not sure about them having a property for the `EditBox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I have found the following fix that allows for what I want. Instead of binding to SelectedItem property, I bound to Text property. Then I was able to create a new list item with the entered information if needed in the lost focus event.